# ios7 when I present a view which contains a searchbar, and then i set it becomeFirstResponder,it will appear a strange animal and I don't wanted it

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisearchbar, becomefirstresponder

Under ios7 when I present (don't push) a viewController which contains a searchbar, and then set the place holder in order to see the animal and then I set it becomeFirstResponder,it will appear a animal and I don't wanted it.

Code:

```
UISearchBar *bar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 300, 44)];
[self.view addSubview:bar];
bar.placeholder = @"I'm going to Turkey";

- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);
```

This will not appear in ios 8 just in ios7. Why? And how to dismiss it?

Comment: Try posting some code showing what you have already done

Comment: second is just as :
UISearchBar *bar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 300, 300, 44)];
    [self.view addSubview:bar];
    bar.placeholder = @"I'm going to Turkey";
the first you should use this method to second:
- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0);